# how to add to an HTML time element

Tags: javascript, html, input, time

How can I use javascript to add to an existing HTML Time element.  I have an html time element and want to be able to press a button that adds one minute to the current time.  I don't want to use input type time.  This is my existing code:

```html
<body>
  <time id = 'time'> 10:00 </time>
  <button onclick = "addTime();">addTime</button>
  <script>
    function addTime(){

      document.getElementById('time').innerHTML += '01:00'
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

but this just appends the time as a string.  Is there an easy way to fix this?

Comment: Put a `Date` `var` in your javascript, then manipulate that `Date` object, i.e. add a minute to that, then `.toString()` it for display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Date.prototype.setMinutes()` with first two numbers of `.innerHTML` of element, `Date.prototype.setSeconds()` with parameter `0`

```html
<body>
  <time id='time'> 10:00 </time>
  <button onclick="addTime();">addTime</button>
  <script>
    const time = document.getElementById('time')
    let date = new Date();   
    
    function addTime() {
      date.setMinutes(1 + +time.innerHTML.match(/\d{2}/)[0]);
      date.setSeconds(0);
      time.innerHTML = String(date).slice(19, 24);
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks you so much!

Answer (score 1):

In html you can put this code:

```
 <time id='time'> <label id="hour">10</label>:<label id="second">00</label> </time>
<button onclick="addTime();">addTime</button>
```

You can run this function:

```
function addTime() {
        var h = parseInt(document.getElementById('hour').innerHTML);
        var s = parseInt(document.getElementById('second').innerHTML);
        s++;
        var add = "0";
        if (s < 10) {
            add = "0" + s;
        }
        else {
            add = s;
        }
        if (s == 60) {
            add = "00";
            h = h + 1;
        }
        if (h == 25) {
            h = 1;
        }
        document.getElementById('hour').innerHTML = h;
        document.getElementById('second').innerHTML = add;
    }
```